# Why does my gun fire once upon loading in?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a gun with multiple firing modes. Upon loading in the weapon (both through loading the scene and through switching to another gun and back to it) it will fire a single shot with sound and light. What is causing it to fire this one bullet and how do I stop the weapon from doing so?

I already tried to add a delay before it should be allowed to fire by making the 1  higher in start. I also tried to add more time to "timeBeforeShooting" in the Void auto section. Setting "shooting" to false and true instead of leaving it blank did not help either.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AutomaticGun1 : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum firingMode
{
    auto = 1,
    semi = 2,
    burst = 3
}

[SerializeField] private firingMode currentFiringMode = firingMode.auto;

[SerializeField] private LayerMask enemyLayer;
[SerializeField] private float damage;
[SerializeField] private float fireRate;

private float timeBeforeShooting;
private bool shooting;
private int firingModeID = 1;

public Camera playerView;
public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
public AudioSource bang;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    timeBeforeShooting = 1 / fireRate;

    playerView.GetComponent<Camera>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
    {
        firingModeID++;

        if(firingModeID > 3)
        {
            firingModeID = 1;
        }

        currentFiringMode = (firingMode)firingModeID;

        Debug.Log(firingModeID);
    }

    switch(currentFiringMode)
    {
        case firingMode.auto:
            auto();
            break;

        case firingMode.semi:
            semi();
            break;

        case firingMode.burst:
            burst();
            break;
    }
}



void auto()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (timeBeforeShooting <= 0f)
        {
            muzzleFlash.Play();
            bang.Play();

            Ray gunRay = new Ray(playerView.transform.position, playerView.transform.forward);

            if (Physics.Raycast(gunRay, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 100f, enemyLayer))
            {
                if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out enemy1 enemyHit))
                {
                    enemyHit.SubtractHealth(damage);
                    Debug.Log(enemyHit.health);
                }
            }

            timeBeforeShooting = 1 / fireRate;
        }

        else
        {
            timeBeforeShooting -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        timeBeforeShooting = 0f;
    }
}

void semi()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (timeBeforeShooting <= 0f)
        {
            muzzleFlash.Play();
            bang.Play();

            Ray gunRay = new Ray(playerView.transform.position, playerView.transform.forward);

            if (Physics.Raycast(gunRay, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 100f, enemyLayer))
            {
                if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out enemy1 enemyHit))
                {
                    enemyHit.SubtractHealth(damage);
                    Debug.Log(enemyHit.health);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void burst()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !shooting)
    {
        StartCoroutine(burstShots(3));
        shooting = true;
    }
}

IEnumerator burstShots(int timesToShoot)
{
    for (int timesShot = 1; timesShot <= timesToShoot; timesShot++)
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();
        bang.Play();

        Ray gunRay = new Ray(playerView.transform.position, playerView.transform.forward);

        if (Physics.Raycast(gunRay, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 100f, enemyLayer))
        {
            if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out enemy1 enemyHit))
            {
                enemyHit.SubtractHealth(damage);
                Debug.Log(enemyHit.health);
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f / fireRate);
    }
    shooting = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Both animation and audio source have play on awake properties. Are they checked off?

Comment: @bartol44 This was it, didn't even know these were a thing. Let alone that they were ticked by default.